# Menu icons printing using arrays not working?

Tags: c

Hi friends I have these project where I am going to display around 10 icons on main screen, every icons display another 5 images when you select it(those are different in numbers but we will consider it as five of each). IT is a sort of main screen and sub-screen. Now I have these almost 88 images to be displayed on screen as icons. 
I have created const char array for each image, so I have a list of 88 const char type of arrays with little informative name for each. My idea is to create another array using all these names and call them whenever it is necessary.  As example below:

```
 const char  *arr_1[] = {"one_ele_zero", "one_ele_one", "one_ele_two", "one_ele_three"};

 const char  *arr_2[] = {"two_ele_zero", "two_ele_one", "two_ele_two", "two_ele_three"};

 const char  *arr_3[] = {"three_ele_zero", "three_ele_one", "three_ele_two", "three_ele_three"};


 const char **arr_all[] = {arr_1, arr_2, arr_3};


 int main()
 {
     printf("%s\n",*arr_all[0]);

     system("PAUSE");

     return 0;


 }
```

This code compiles, I can print first array 0th location string, but I am not getting how to print the rest. 
I am new in C if you guys think that there are other ways to do this ….please suggest me or guide me to some example program….thanks.

Comment: Do some research on looping in c

Comment: you should read the "C Programming Language" by Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie

Comment: You should use a loop (for, while, or dowhile)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this,

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 for(j=0;j<3;j++)
     printf("%s\n",*(arr_all[i]+j));
```

Your `arr_all[]` contains the base address of `arr_1[]`,`arr_2[]` and `arr_3[]`. If you use only

`printf("%s\n",*arr_all[0]);` prints only the 1st element of arr_1[] 
`printf("%s\n",*arr_all[i]);` with `0<=i<3` prints only the 1st element of each arr_1[] 
`printf("%s\n",*(arr_all[i]+j));` with `0<=i<3` and `0<=j<3` takes base address of `arr_x[]` (ar_1, arr_2, arr_3) array and prints each element of that array using `j`

Comment: @hi_impact Updated the answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s\n", arr_all[0][1]);//one_ele_one
```